# Using an Editor to Validate User-Entered Text in specific column

Tags: java, swing, jtable

i don't understand how does the DefaultEditor work!?

i have read jtable tutorial,but it doesn't help me.
can someone explain for me how i can set DefaultEditor for a specific column in my JTable for example i want  the values of the  first column  are Integer...

```
table.getColumnModel().getColumn(1).setCellEditor(Integer.class, new IntegerEditor(0, 100));
```

my problem is :cannot find symbol:class IntegerEditor !

Comment: what exactly is the problem: setting the editor? implementing a custom editor? doing the validation as such? ... ? Without more detail - best with a SSCCE - your question is not answerable and might be closed

Comment: @kleopatra my problem is :cannot find symbol:class IntegerEditor !

Comment: okay, then you'll need to take a step back and learn some basics of java and/or working with your tool, be it the plain command line compiler or an IDE :) Nothing much we can do for you: the message is quite clear, happens if the class isn't on the classpath. Reasons might be a missing import statement or maybe it doesn't even exist? Cant tell from here.